# How to execute script code from bash shell stdin?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want to execute script code like python from bash standard input, because I don't want to write a script to file first. And how to do ?
If I want to run python code from bash standard input like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print 'hello world'
```

$cat mycode.py | bash -s

But it doesn't work. An error showed:

```
Warning: unknown mime-type for "hello world" -- using "application/octet-stream"
```

Error: no such file "hello world"

Comment: yes,I correct the title,thanks.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Acturally, I want to run script code like python ,redirect codes to bash standard input.

Comment: see update t my answer

Comment: How did `mime-type` and `application/octet-stream` get into a simple bash question?  Are you accessing bash from something other than a tty?

Comment: I want to run script code like python ,redirect python codes to bash standard input then I want bash identfy the python mime-type

Comment: You want to identify the mime type, but isn't this about executing the python code through bash? This could be valid if you're accessing a remote system where you don't have io permissions like a spawned shell and such right? ;) *sarcasm*

Answer (score 4):

*But it doesn't work.An error showed: 
Warning: unknown mime-type for "hello world" -- using "application/octet-stream" Error: no such file "hello world"*

Of cource, bash don't know command `hello world` and system suggest install something. Below can work

```
python -c 'print "ls -l"' | bash
```

Comment: python -c  ,support indent ?

Comment: Yes, but it bad idea. It good thing for very simple and short writeonly scripts. If ypur script not trivial, then use `python myfile.py | bash`. In this case, if bash got coreect input it will work well.

Answer (score 1):

As variant you can make similar to this scenario:

```
$ cat test.py 
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    sys.stdout.write("ls -l")

$ python test.py | bash
итого 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miha miha 91 авг.  28 12:21 test.py
$ chmod +x test.py
$ ./test.py | bash
итого 4
-rwxrwxr-x 1 miha miha 91 авг.  28 12:21 test.py
```